# Apache2 with PDF and PHP - "This file does not start with "%PDF-"

Tags: php, pdf, apache2, nginx

I have been trying to find the reason for this error for weeks now - and I have come up a blank. The system uses PHP to generate dynamic .pdf files.

I have three servers: Dev (Win7 with Apache2), Test (Ubuntu 10.4 with nginx), and Live (Ubuntu 10.10 with nginx). All are running php5 and the system I have developed - same code. Equivalent, same config.

I have many browsers I have tested things with: DevIE (win7, IE8), DevFF (Win7 Firefox 3.5), DevSaf (win, Safari), LaptopFF (WinXP, Firfox 3.5), Laptop IE(WinXP, IE8 Test (Ubuntu FF3.5), and users (mostly IE8 on Win 7 and Win XP).

- When I generate a PDF from Test it works correctly in all browsers (except Users which I can't test).
- When I generate a PDF from Dev it fails from DevIE, DevFF and DevSaf, but calling for it from Test works.
- Apache2 always fails from the same machine.
- From the laptop, using FF succeeds, and using IE8 fails (see below).

The users are reporting intermittent problems. It fails, and then the repeat the request and it succeeds.

When it fails....

The log of the generated PDF is shown, sending the right sort of size reply (500KB to 1.8MB) with a 200 OK result. This is *sometimes* followed about 10 seconds later with a repeat of the same URL - but this generates the log-on screen (again 200 OK reply), but only 2K in size. The implication is that it was requested without the cookie.

Adobe Reader tries to display the log-on page, with the inevitable `"This file does not start with "%PDF-"` error message.

Except for when I try with the laptop and IE8 - then it fails with show source showing a 4 line html file with an empty body!

The system has been working for over a year - and only started failing with a change of production server about 2 months ago. The test version was not changed at this time, but started to fail also.

I have tried all sorts of headers, but nothing I have tried makes any difference. The current set of headers is:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$this->pdfFilename().'"');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Pragma: public");
$when = date('r',time()+20);  // expire in 20 seconds
header("Expires: $when");
```

I've tried replacing inline with attachment. Adding and removing all sorts of no-cache headers. All to no avail.

The PDF is requested in a new window, by JavaScript - and is followed 8 seconds later by a refresh. I have tested without the new window, and without the refresh - no change.

I have has a few (small) PDFs served by the Dev server. So I have raised every limit I can think of. Now it always fails.

So I have a Windows Apache2.2 server that fails when browsed from the same machine and succeeds when browsed from other machines in Firefox.

There is no proxy or cache mechanism involved other than that in the browsers.

Has anyone any ideas about what might be going wrong? As I said, I have been testing and eliminating things for nearly 4 weeks now, on and off, and I have not yet even identified the failing component.

Comment: Some more input. Tested the Dev server from my wife's Win7 machine - and everything worked just fine. Its looking as if it is something to do with 64 bit windows 7.

Comment: is it def the headers causing a problem or could there be a fault with the pdf generation part of the code?

Comment: The PDF content is correct when browsed from Linux using FF, 32 bit Windows 7 using FF and IE8, and when the server is nginx and fast-cgi. So I think it is correct. If the headers were wrong it would never work. And why/where does the repeat log comefrom 10 seconds later? The PDF actually takes 1 to 2 seconds to generate and serve when it is going to be displayed - but it takes 10 seconds to fail when it is going to fail.  Still puzzled.

Comment: I had a such a problem around a year ago. The problem appeared suddenly, as certain users switched from the internet to our corporate intranet. At the server-side, everything worked as expected. No error log entries. The PDF had definitely been moved to the client. I fixed it by sending additional headers. Tomorrow, I'll try to find the HTTP hesder set.

Comment: Ah, over here, everything worked fine, as we asked infected users to right click the PDF link and download the file - and then launch PDF reader.

Comment: You might try adding a length header in case the EOF is not being recognized. I have an app that serves PDFs generated on the fly, and it only uses 3 headers:   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Length: $size");

Comment: @Ian, quick question - What link is being used to call the pdf? Last year I developed an app that produced a PDF, and discovered that some browsers were (wrongly in my view) inferring the content from the link - so on IE6 (for example) a link to myphp?pdfdocid=12 would produce an error (although users could still right-click and save. We got round this by creating a handler script and an HTACCESS file that allowed you to request \docs\pdfdoc12.pdf. This solved the problem for us.

Comment: @Stefan - If you could look out the header set that  would be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary The url is typically something like /sop/print/quote123.pdf - this is converted by mod-rewrite or the nginx equivalent into /sop/index.php?act=print#type=quote#id=123

Comment: @bryan. I'll give it a try, but 99% of times the genereation works fine on the live (only had 1 problem in 2 weeks), so I doubt the problem is in the generation.

Answer (score 3):

This is really tough to troubleshoot - for starters, (please excuse my bluntness, but) this a prime example of what a pipeline should not look like:

- Three different operating systems.
- Probably at least two different versions of PHP.
- Two different webservers.

But anyway, a few general hints on debugging PHP:

- make sure to enable `error_log` and `log_errors` in `php.ini` (set `display_errors = Off`)
- use the most verbose `error_reporting`
- set `access_log` and `error_log` in nginx.
- crank up log level in nginx (I'm guessing you use php-cgi or php-fpm, so you should be able to see what status the backend emits when the download attemp fails).

Furthermore:

1. You haven't shared how the PDF is generated - are you sure all libraries used here are the same or at least somewhat the same across all systems?
2. In any case, just to be sure I would save the PDF on the server before it is *offered* to download. This allows you to troubleshoot the actual file — to see if the PDF generation actually worked.
3. Since you're saving the PDF, I'd see about putting it in a *public* folder, so you can see if you can just redirect to it after it's generated. And only if this works, then I'd work on a force-download kind of thing.
4. I would replicate the production environment in all stages. ;-) You need your dev server to be exactly like the production environment. For your own workstation, I'd recommend a VM (e.g. through Virtualbox with Ubuntu 10.10).

Let me know this gets you somewhere and reply with updates. :-)

**Update**:

I'd investigate these two headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Definitely helps with cache busting.

Comment: Agree on all count. Point 2 is a must do to clear out any issue with the PDF generation itself..

Comment: Reallly good, pragmatic advice. Agree with @Ben - Point 2 is the next thing you do. ++

Comment: Thanks Till - Ecellent advice. Option 2 followed by Option 3 is how I developed it, so it will be possible to switch back. The PDF is genereated using http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf version 009 and uses exactly the same code on all machines. Switching to 10.10 is on the to-do list - the production switch was triggered by a hard disk crash 2 weeks ago. When using Ubuntu 10:04 in production the problems were occuring at about a similar rate.

Comment: Further update: - I have updated the test serve to ununtu 10:10 and spent a long time trying to get it to fail. It worked perfectly. Using FF I once got a "insufficient data for image" error, saved the file, repeated the request, (which worked) and compared resulting .pdf files. They were identical. Using IE8 the results are that the PDF dispalys in the new window, and the old window refreshesbut when the new/PDF window is closed, a popup appears "IE has stopped working". After acknowledging that, I get a "This tab has been recovered" message.

Answer (score 0):

These are the headers, which finally worked in a similar situation in one of my apps:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header( "Content-Type: application/pdf" );
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"YourPDF_" . time() . ".pdf\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". strlen( $pdfData ) );
```

I added the time() code to make the filename change each time, so that it likely passes all proxies.

From time to time but seldom, the problem re-appears. Then, we ask our clients to download the file using the browser context menu.

PS: The app uses ezPDF found here: http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/

Comment: Stackoverflow somehow doesn't let me comment, so I added the headers to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Till. I'll add your headers to the current ones.